HHL eigenvalue inversion step with larger number of clock qubits that number of eigenvalues
Reading about the HHL algorithm (this paper/arXiv and this paper/arXiv) I came up with the following question: if I have, say, 2 eigenvalues for which I need, say, 5 qubits for the best QPE algorithm, how to choose the angles for the eigenvalue inversion? Because I saw only numerical examples for $n$ eigenvalues and $n$ qubits
